# Intent-filters (https) on Android 8 (Oreo)

Tags: android, https, intentfilter

I'm having problems with intent-filters on Android 8.0 (oreo). I define my intent filter like that:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*.webpage.com"   android:pathPattern="/.*/offers" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.webpage.com" android:pathPattern="/.*/offers" />
</intent-filter>
```

But if I click on a link with https scheme the app isn't launched, if I click on a link with http scheme it does. If I try both links on a Android < 8.0 both links works. What I'm doing wrong??

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe it has to do with this restriction: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html stating that "apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest."